# Android Maps V2 metersToEquatorPixels where/what is the equivalent in new maps?

Tags: android, maps, android-maps-v2, projection

Android Maps had this nice little method on the projection for a map, MetersToEquatorPixels that let you convert between pixels and meters at the equator, and then a quick little multiplication of that result by *(1/Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitudeofmap) would tell you how many pixels would represent the equivalent for that latitude.

What the heck is the equivalent in Maps V2?  If I want to say, draw a legend, to show distance, I have to know how much distance each pixel represents in lat/lon distance, and since this method is now gone, I have no idea how the heck I can get this... So what is the equivalent in V2?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question??

Comment: I did not, I had to do write some math on my own to get the equivalent, don't have the code in front of me, but will try to look it up this evening.

Comment: That will be great if you can post it as an answer so other can benefit. I will plus 1 it :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it can help you: I take it from:https://gist.github.com/amay077/6879638

```
public static int metersToEquatorPixels(GoogleMap map, LatLng base, float meters) {
final double OFFSET_LON = 0.5d;

Location baseLoc = new Location("");
baseLoc.setLatitude(base.latitude);
baseLoc.setLongitude(base.longitude);

Location dest = new Location("");
dest.setLatitude(base.latitude);
dest.setLongitude(base.longitude + OFFSET_LON);

double degPerMeter = OFFSET_LON / baseLoc.distanceTo(dest); // 1m は何度？
double lonDistance = meters * degPerMeter; // m を度に変換

Projection proj = map.getProjection();
Point basePt = proj.toScreenLocation(base);
Point destPt = proj.toScreenLocation(new LatLng(base.latitude, base.longitude + lonDistance));

return Math.abs(destPt.x - basePt.x);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.. What is the offset_lon ?

Comment: Your welcome ... I don't know exactly. but I think it covers the error! for being more accurate ...

Comment: and what about base LatLng? could you please correct what is that coordinates?